# Iterating through SOAP requests from a properties file

Tags: java, web-services, soap, properties, configuration

I am writing a java plugin that I plan to use to test a number of web services. These SOAPs for the web services are located in a properties file, and are grouped under which WSDL they fall under (Subscriber, Network, User, etc...). Also, there are some regexs associated with each web service to test the response against.

`Properties Example`

```
#Web services to be tested and regexes to test responses
 #List of web service groups used (WSDLs)
 webservice.list = SubscriberMgmt,NetworkMgmt

 # < -- SubscriberMgmt -- >
 #getSubscriberDevices
 webservice.subscriber = <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.blah.blah.com"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:getSubscriberDevices><PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber><LastName></LastName><MACAddress></MACAddress><ExternalId></ExternalId><AccountExternalId>john</AccountExternalId><IPAddress></IPAddress></ws:getSubscriberDevices></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
 webservice.SubscriberMgmt.regex = subscriberId="(.+?)"
 webservice.SubscriberMgmt.regex.1 = externalId="(.+?)"

 #getMpegResultsById
 webservice.subscriber.1 = <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.blah.blah.com"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:getMpegResultsById><SubscriberId>100016</SubscriberId><Duration>2880</Duration></ws:getMpegResultsById></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> 
 webservice.SubscriberMgmt.1.regex = id="(.+?)"
 webservice.SubscriberMgmt.1.regex.1 = externalId="(.+?)"
```

I currently have code to connect using each WSDL from the properties file, so say when the 'webservicegroup' variable is SubscriberMgmt, I'd like to test the .subscriber web service(s) and check the responses if it contains the corresponding regex(es). (the 'data' variable only corresponds to one SOAP request from the property file at the moment)

```
//Soap Request
        try
        {
            for(String webservicegroup : webserviceList)
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://" + server + "/webservices/" + webservicegroup);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
                String loginEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
                loginEnc = loginEnc.replaceAll("\n", "");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + loginEnc);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                //Send request
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                //Save response
                String line;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response += line;
                }
                in.close();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on the best way of doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: could you expand your question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your connection and POST/GET code is working:

Step 1: Get the entire response as a string:

```
String response = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream), "UTF-8");
```

In the above line of code, the ByteStreams class is part of google's guava library. Similar code can be found in apache commons-io, if you prefer that.

Step 2: Test Regular expressions:

```
if( response.matches(regex) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, building a custom testing software mini empire from scratch.
Use SOAPUI open source version to test web services.  It allows you to:

- generate SOAP tests from web service endpoint WSDL, saving manual labour
- avoid processing "pre-canned" SOAP strings and parsing files
- automatically generate mocks of your service endpoints, including ability to programmatically control custom responses.
- implement test step logic including loops, branches, invoking other test steps, running scripts, and reading/writing parameters from/to property files and data sources (although you must programatically navigate & modify XmlHolder instances via scripts if you wish to "data-drive" your tests)
- Execute SOAP, REST, security & load testing of web services, and also JDBC and HTTP test calls.
- Integrates with the common build and continuous integration tools for test automation (TDD & continuous delivery).
- Use SOAPUI operations within your IDE, via plugins.

It's considered fairly standard "best practice" for testing web services.

To checks SOAP response messages for valid content, using the open source version of SOAPUI:

- you can use [XPath or XQuery expressions to validate the XML](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html).
- you can use [script assertions](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/script-assertions.html)

  E.g. if your SOAP response is:

  ```
   <soap:Body>
       <GetEnumResponse xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/">
           <GetEnumResult>
               <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
               <StatusId>0</StatusId>
           </GetEnumResult>
           <enumsInformation>
               <EnumInformation>
                   <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
                   <ConstraintId>5000006</ConstraintId>
                   <EnumValue>xyz</EnumValue>
                   <Index>10</Index>
               </EnumInformation>
           </enumsInformation>
       </GetEnumResponse>
   </soap:Body>
  ```

  You can script:

  ```
   import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
   def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)

   holder.namespaces["tal"]="http://www.xyz.com/"
   def node = holder.getNodeValue("//tal:ConstraintId[1]");
   log.info(node);
   assert node == "5000006";
  ```
- You can even use the maximum power of standard java regex processing.

  Create java classes that do the regex processing and put them into a jar file and place in soapUIinstallation/bin/ext as explained [here](http://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/tag/soapui/).

  Or wrap your SOAPUI Test inside a JUnit test method, and add standard java code at end to check regexs.  This also eases test automation & allows any non-web service tests to be executed as well.  This approach works with SOAPUI open source version, whereas the alternative of using SOAPUI assertion steps requires the Pro version.

  Steps:

  1. If you choose, install the SOAPUI plugin in your IDE
  2. Use SOAPUI to create a test suite
  3. Use SOAPUI to create test case(s) within the test suite
  4. Use SOAPUI to create test step(s) within the test suite.  This is the core of using SOAPUI.
  5. Create a Java project in your IDE.  Within this project, add a JUnit test case.
  6. Add all JARs from SoapUI  bin  and  lib  directories to Java Build Path.
  7. Within the Junit Test case, add code to execute a SOAPUI test step
  8. Obtain the MessageExchange object, get the response from it, and then get headers, content or attachments.  Run a regex check on result.

  The following is indicative only.  Not intended to be a working example.

  ```
   package com.example;

   import org.junit.Test;
   import com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner;

   public class SoapUIProject {

       // runs an entire SOAPUI test suite
       @Test
       public void soapTest1() throws Exception {     
           SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
           runner.setProjectFile("/path/to/your/W3Schools-Tutorial-soapui-project.xml");
           runner.run();      
       }

       // runs a single SOAPUI test step - and checks response matches a regex
       @Test
       public void soapTest2() throws Exception {     
           WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" ); 
           TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("My Test Suite"); 
           TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("My Test Case");
           TestCaseRunner testCaseRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase,null);

           // Must have test step setup as WsdlMessageExchange for cast to work
           WsdlMessageExchangeTestStepResult testStepResult = (WsdlMessageExchangeTestStepResult)testStep.runTestStepByName("My Test Step"); 

           // TestStep testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("My Test Step");
           // TestCaseRunContext testCaseRunContext = new WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
           // testStep.prepare(testCaseRunner, testCaseRunContext); 
           // WsdlMessageExchangeTestStepResult testStepResult = (WsdlMessageExchangeTestStepResult)testStep.run(testCaseRunner, testCaseRunContext); 

           MessageExchange[] messageExchanges = testStepResult.getMessageExchanges();
           for (MessageExchange me : messageExchanges) {
               String response =  me.getResponseContentAsXML();
               // do any desired regex processing
               // can use any desired assertions
           }
           assertEquals( Status.FINISHED, runner.getStatus() ); 
       }

   }
  ```

Further refs: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#3-xml-nodes
  http://books.google.com.au/books?id=DkWx7xZ263gC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false